# Mongoose/Nodejs validation error handling, memory leak issue

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am running into a case where nodejs seems to be leaking memory when mongoose objects are attempted be created, but fail because of validation errors.  It seems strange to me, and I am seeking help from the community in getting to the bottom of it.

In the sample code where I've tried to recreate my problem, I have a very simple Mongoose model which validates one of its fields to be non-negative number. Repeated attempts at creation of invalid objects (with `XVALUE` as `-1` in the code below), I see memory growing forever.  But valid objects (with `XVALUE` as `+1`, say) works as expected, without any leaks.  I am tracking memory using `process.memoryUsage().heapUsed` variable.

How do I get rid of the memory leak when attempts are made to create invalid objects?  If I am using mongoose incorrectly, any suggestions on improving the usage would be much appreciated.

Versions:  mongoose -  3.8.x and nodejs - 0.10.x.

The following is the sample code I have used to recreate my problem:

```
(function() {
  var MAX_ITER_COUNT, MyModel, MyStuff, Schema, XVALUE, addEntry, conn, iterCount, mongoose;

  mongoose = require("mongoose");

  conn = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://@127.0.0.1:27017/memtest');

  conn.on("error", function(err) {
    return console.error(err);
  });

  Schema = mongoose.Schema;

  MyStuff = new Schema({
    x: {
      type: Number
    }
  });

  XVALUE = -1;

  MyStuff.path("x").validate((function(val) {
    if (val < 0) {
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }));

  MyModel = conn.model("MyStuff", MyStuff, "stuff");

  iterCount = 0;

  MAX_ITER_COUNT = 100 * 1000;

  addEntry = function() {
    var currentMem, x;
    currentMem = Math.round(process.memoryUsage().heapUsed / 1024 / 1024);
    console.log("" + iterCount + " - memory is: " + currentMem + " MB");
    x = new MyModel({
      x: XVALUE
    });
    return x.save(function(err) {
      if (err) {
        console.log("" + iterCount + " - failed");
      } else {
        console.log("" + iterCount + " - Save successful");
      }
      if (iterCount < MAX_ITER_COUNT) {
        addEntry();
      }
      return iterCount++;
    });
  };

  conn.on("open", addEntry);

}).call(this);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's happening is that with an invalid document, the `x.save` async operation completes immediately, calling its callback as soon as its parent `addEntry` function call completes.  This leaves no chance for garbage collection to run and the memory usage keeps growing.

To fix this, put the recursive `addEntry` call within a call to [`setImmediate`](http://nodejs.org/api/all.html#all_setimmediate_callback_arg) to give GC a chance to run between iterations:

```
addEntry = function() {
  var currentMem, x;
  currentMem = Math.round(process.memoryUsage().heapUsed / 1024 / 1024);
  console.log("" + iterCount + " - memory is: " + currentMem + " MB");
  x = new MyModel({
    x: XVALUE
  });
  return x.save(function(err) {
    if (err) {
      console.log("" + iterCount + " - failed");
    } else {
      console.log("" + iterCount + " - Save successful");
    }
    if (iterCount < MAX_ITER_COUNT) {
      setImmediate(addEntry);
    }
    return iterCount++;
  });
};
```

Comment: Thank you! I can confirm that my sample code works for me with your suggested change.